# Render Control in httpHandler

Tags: c#, httphandler

How can I render a control (TreeView to be specific) in httpHandler?
I have tried the following:

```
 var p = new Panel();
 p.Controls.Add(plcLinks);
 p.Controls.Add(htmlTreeView);
 var sw = new StringWriter();
 var writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
 page.RenderControl(writer);
 context.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
```

The result was a simple bulleted list not a tree view control as I accepted.
How can I get a tree view control as a result in mine page?

Comment: Did you not want a simple bullet list? What result did you expect?

Comment: I want to get a treeview (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx)

Comment: A `TreeView` is rendered as a regular HTML bullet list, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, But I don't get the collapse/expand icon near each node

Comment: I think you are right. checking it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a change in the css file

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
 var p = new Panel();
 p.Controls.Add(plcLinks);
 p.Controls.Add(htmlTreeView);
 p.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(context.Response.Output));
```